# EGOTableViewPullRefresh Too quick

Tags: ios, networking, pull-to-refresh

I've put EGOTableViewPullRefresh in my project. However, I've noticed one troubling thing. If I ever need to download a (semi-moderately) large file by pulling down to refresh, EGOTableViewPullRefresh says that I am done downloading much faster than I really am.

Is there a way to make EGOTableViewPullRefresh show that is is still downloading. In other words, I would like the words "loading" to last longer on the screen when I pull down to refresh. Actually, I would like "loading" to be on the screen until it is done loading.

In viewDidloadmethod:

```
  if (_refreshHeaderView == nil) {

    EGORefreshTableHeaderView *view = [[EGORefreshTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - self.tableView.bounds.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.tableView.bounds.size.height)];
    view.delegate = self;
    [self.tableView addSubview:view];
    _refreshHeaderView = view;
}
//  update the last update date
[_refreshHeaderView refreshLastUpdatedDate];
```

Comment: in this function doneLoadingTableViewData

Answer (score 0):

You should set pullTableIsRefreshing to NO in block

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
```

//your data fetching code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //your UI code
         self.tableView.pullTableIsRefreshing = NO;



     });
});
```

Comment: pullTableIsRefreshing is variable of EGOTableViewPullRefresh library and the loading view which appears depends on the visibilty of this variable, So in my code i am hiding the loading view when all server request is completed and when displaying the UI
So loading view will not disappear untill you set pullTableIsRefreshing to NO

Comment: property pullTableIsRefreshing not found on object of uitableview. That is what I get.

Comment: your table should be of type Pulltableview instead of uitableview, as you are using EGOTableViewPullRefresh and kindly refer the sample given in library for more clarification

Comment: I did refer to the sample, and I don't know what a Pulltableview is. I searched the sample project and it does not know what a Pulltableview is.

Comment: i would request you to paste your code so that i can see what mistake are you doing.
As i have used EGOTableViewPullRefresh in many projects and performs well. Good library

Comment: First, thanks for your patience. Your help is truly appreciated. Second, I (and probably you) would prefer that I not just dump a code and then let sort through it. With that it mind, do you have in mind what code you would like to see?